# I am having error when installing npm install mongoose in my folder

Tags: npm, installation

npm ERR! code CERT_NOT_YET_VALID
npm ERR! errno CERT_NOT_YET_VALID
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose failed, reason: certificate is not yet valid

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hasib Alam\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-12T06_16_42_472Z-debug-0.log

This Shows when i try to install mongoose in my folder please can anyone help me with this problem

I am installing npm mongoose but it is not installing